# Google Script to pull certain information from email and put in a Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hoping to be able to automate an annoying part of my day...
The emails always come formatted the same ... here's the part of the email I'm looking to pull the data from.

Item#: SS10MM
Product Description: 10mm SOCKET
Vendor: Store
Vendor Item Code: 10MSS
Complaint: Lost another one, really wish you could put a GPS chip in these!

Is it possible to have a script pull that information and put each of those in a corresponding column?

I have attempted to work with some of the scripts I have found online when searching 'parse email to sheet', but those seem to be trying to bring the entire email over, which is obviously not what I'm looking for.

Help??

Edit:  I guess current code might help, huh?

```
function getGmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox is:unread from:
(you@aol.com) "TEST EMAIL"');

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
var msg=messages[j].getPlainBody(); 
var msg=msg.trim() 
}
}
result1(msg)
}
function result1(range) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
var lr=sheet1.getLastRow()
var output=[]
var line=range.split("\n")
for(j=0;j<line.length;j++){
output.push(line[j].split(" "))
}
var output1=[]
for(k=0;k<output.length;k++){
if(output[k]!=""){
output1.push(output[k])
}}
sheet1.getRange(lr+1, 1, output1.length, 
output1[0].length).setValues(output1)
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Post some code!

Comment: @Brian  I mean, I guess that might help

Comment: @jdc03 You changed the formatting of the email section. How does it come in exactly? On new lines like that or all on one line?

Comment: @ChrisW  like it is now.  Didn't look at the preview before I initially posted.

Comment: @jdc03 I've update the code with the new formatting. Should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/richard-to/8797504) and added a little bit to get you started. You have to setup a [Time-driven Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to run the `main_emailDataToSpreadsheet()` function and have the emails labeled as 'pending'.

**UPDATED:**

```
 //Modified from https://gist.github.com/richard-to/8797504 < http://pipetree.com/qmacro/blog/2011/10/04/automated-email-to-task-mechanism-with-google-apps-script/

var LABEL_PENDING = "pending";
var LABEL_DONE = "done";

// processPending(sheet)
// Process any pending emails and then move them to done
function processPending_(sheet) {

  // Get out labels by name
  var label_pending = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(LABEL_PENDING);
  var label_done = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(LABEL_DONE);

  // The threads currently assigned to the 'pending' label
  var threads = label_pending.getThreads();

  // Process each one in turn, assuming there's only a single
  // message in each thread
  for (var t in threads) {
    var thread = threads[t];

    // Gets the message body
    var message = thread.getMessages()[0].getPlainBody();
    Logger.log(message);
    // Process the messages here
    message = message.substr(message.search("Item#:")); //Get the beginning of the important part + cut off the beginning
    Logger.log(message);
    message = message.split("\n");
    Logger.log(message[0].split(": ")[1]);

    var data = [message[0].split(": ")[1], //Item#
                message[1].split(": ")[1], //Prod. Desc.
                message[2].split(": ")[1], //Vendor
                message[3].split(": ")[1], //Ven. Item Code
                message[4].split(": ")[1] //Complaint
               ];
    // Add message to sheet
    sheet.appendRow(data);

    // Set to 'done' by exchanging labels
    thread.removeLabel(label_pending);
    thread.addLabel(label_done);
  }
}
```

Comment: @jdc03 I've updated my answer. This should work for you now. Did you get a chance to try it?

Comment: Had to make a tiny edit, but it seems to work!  When I have some time later I'll dig a little deeper into it and see if I can't get it fully functioning as I want.  Thank you!! @ChrisW

Comment: Spent a little more time with it today... made some adjustments here and there and have it functioning the way I was hoping it would.  Thank you!!

Comment: @jdc03 No problem! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

i try use similar script from video, is work fine , but maybe know how need extract  text from body ?
i want extract selected  lines

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXRpE.jpg)

```css
" 
We're on it!
 ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌  ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌  ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌  ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌  ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌  ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌  ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌  

[image:  ] 
[image: Walmart home page] 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=IDmq3p6D24pjubsFDWevaJSJp%2FcWAHUkWOb8rG474YKQF1BHf%2FRe1PrWbaG72fzN9gm2Cu5SJzL6IxMgVCwnSs0rC%2FDdGezAtu%2FTDorTgKusN9SThQ49EBC9ppRO9LnhzzgSeG04ojrI8uEPTKyVwJRctEuGxVEir7ZtUQIQjVv6JyTSvrLopMoDyotfuXj6Ma7Q3walhts6sZqLzDhcHX99%2B1wmDioVlV%2F82S2XOx%2Flmqg5aJ6D%2F67KCw6IGZLCmxkkhsDkttxm0Sf6cfw2uQa4Lah5QmRtG8lwd5ld2wTqekWabuf%2B5Z4sJGbS7Wz2QZyECrszwtp2USm%2FTT8rT8zmHDTBIlNP%2FvtBpg2CyQ6j%2BDJceJ2YA%2BzzFjpKIZlaic6PO5vqdc2Ixj6UtL%2FXf2tp1G7kQdLKEu%2FOJKUkbNY%3D&meta=UJ3MbvXTZ0QCoYmcG2SnTkvEtzkMy2E7nXZnfr7uD63Qzz%2FUK%2Fx3YNSK7dEHv5qMI9yBHgjMmr9Q%2Bf0aB7cxwiNFQAD1%2B5vcodGQFbfnhKZYA2KNFEl9S1m5FFwSaRSbTxdd0xvEAPu6GnLGU%2FrSdSZLhFmCWibveRW4j3XAbZBI%2FuBwXzVkW1jtdmbhaKWZyOs6bV0PbyiQXtVbyPlHMg%3D%3D&iv=BlawkXrhquImGaluJqtu2A%3D%3D>
Order date: Wed, Sep 14, 2022
Thanks for your order, Tadas!

We'll get to work on order #2000102-00447433 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=TTiyuDsiGIFcJYlGyB%2Fbel5puD6U0bFFfRNxT%2FFbYXiOpCKXwIYOYgZr1UgWjis%2FYBRPGsRYH2EnKEV8swb5D%2F0%2BxdSvR3sNNv13IUc2HimQXOG8TkXDxCiXFOWf5ezHxcmvktQbyDhSVXympZDfebJsZrkaNcUbRu11CnK7zhCSODorcy3z3AMAdUYiAaGaGnj88zZDTPkXpJJFY9QYy6eYqvV%2F7dkUZXHpW6JIl%2FCnMrJEv8WaBJ77c88Cpmgdz1dqoybFC1zCMa8KSf8JtVxVVrRCPpj4x6wxgPZ66mFqF%2FCRDsjz%2FlYl06w05orOmIryPB144sliq52V%2FgUXyXx%2Fg4bvSGMR4LeyCUKIuzU1rV2oLYeuW6WodhKCQZ5etA8UqA4nN2bi7IthPI35Rf9sv%2Fteao6MxRUxPl3urdfhvhj%2BX3PMpEYPW722YOMXWEhfzix4IKbsgQuA2r%2FK2g%3D%3D&meta=SXCH9y3RD2eIDf2xxWRh1FnUch0bCj5ubaJ2mmZEzMut2suEDXRfrvrLenZLukypULoN1OlXt4ecftMwNy6ddwQ8MgZscA2riLEeupCtCE89fbkMUopwIOxVVPkI5ALvap029ldVuCR%2Bj6WUTftqDHEnYGTc4wwWJGMORNt2g8KzFtbxDpDs%2BkA1y5ougVyJ8uH%2FkzNVhi1DCqMMsx4r0Q%3D%3D&iv=t4KY72Zqg6DnSV81Nojzig%3D%3D> 
right away.
• Your shipment is set to arrive by end of day Thu, Sep 15

You're all set for now. We'll keep you posted, and you can always track 
your order's progress in Order Details 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=3eH%2FL1UYrrYDuhlRc%2F7Xj4pxXD3klKQYOGlM%2Buh96jc0pTglj%2FyNVVj4sQ%2BlnEesUN7iZq6Bp6%2BDQy3RwLMYrOieSnbAED9OnM1b%2BV06J78ZV0THkfwlZCOrr%2Bs7pQuRoDqngdLmHyO%2BV911NjbPGbDv98nlXiO2ftxe1j7DEF0%2ByotGp4lldUiFDmnB00XkcId%2B20RLPzDna%2Fw%2B3HHZh5Uw7HD9s%2B2XIZqyJtXNzm3BpRTC7zi6VL68U9IeILYj62Tde2Ahh%2BOxYJV0zp5LJj0xX9RhZ347dSryMHRdVJpLJQWp6a95%2Fs0WKZKJtAHqmSoDCBtciia%2Bgs686dOKYG0IxztDAAwOy2SS1jKOn2zvBqq9%2B7W8mL6Cov8T7Xgfn6Wl8psx3ftJHQzE7msiuzIyfps0iZH5y7smMBOXgvSRFDx35hjr0SZI8iOUO1S7ZM1ID0AMqDApEtqsbxjk4w%3D%3D&meta=P3%2B3dzVNn33h3Gkg%2FYroxZEKHspJ932wUtFLhR7PLkisW0NR89p1M6k4xMtt%2BlgCQAPKTlkwjcuARovWgLwBI9EyBVRHbrZ5yisg5CVFYKZTKhcPBNqCNSTDIjVh%2FM55qygrxsQDo2bl4KtSiKPiLbzNCiCCWgXReCXYNbaqf6P7fmqtbg3XsNb2jAh1d%2B%2BKbkOykAeFxdlqplVv75HY1A%3D%3D&iv=%2BmKeOWFHuIkif2Mc5igphg%3D%3D>
.
Manage order 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=YIhtLtpJXHRfzbPL%2Blln99njDdvXWKBWYbLPUw8UgMqSM2Sz7SZVkk2JM%2FsqKpJsEqVeJ29E8BsvaSnRZVxHfD0No7QL8dImM9M1F6tgzDPptXpb%2B%2B2h0w01cQ2eGOl7IKVMaYm5%2FOEbvMATpDX3AZ8cyaw58NLYglDgtTiwGENEc1f%2FZgj0INQj%2FiupGfftV3mVcwlpLnt71E8v9Ebv%2BKRflbNcI2D0OFQWZI5AslnI%2BSHibEStOVKZEXJG%2FD%2F2vAYVmNhl9F6A031s7mkxrQdehuagdbbrUENVO98V8xgiKtrfX4k3QtDjy9h0fkidNOx6LRtqvjEKaye9LxailuJqlzNUYLrxcD1XtRLQJ6JQPMENByuKOadz%2Fg2QAdd1s5bSiFWSBdepTSteZ%2BBNG0VwkjXdR1ZyTaYf88oG1j1wTWzZU6l1VuAk1sYkAFRgVAq515vm3bTqRUF1C8J10Q%3D%3D&meta=vPDCnbgIQYQ3N90egmc%2BPrmQOguFst3xYTExuxJfjEgWddkIsAzuk0RGoJxreUdkd4Jyu3h%2BBV6GKagIGuDB0%2BlgzsvJgvd030CIc6gaVGjsy7I9PNn%2BGaaSulAt4YmB%2FbYgG%2Basg8orjRtgl3NpNuRHgXw4G1%2Fm04nfyQW3aJdd44%2FxeF0%2B6xviOibyG2kjcBB4fV8nBroxKfjGoCGUFw%3D%3D&iv=PrbmQFvk%2BZ%2BIJFbaoLs7OA%3D%3D>

P.S. For more information and FAQ, visit our Help Center 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=RU9YZPlDXtx7gm1oZNojDwFWgvp7qIQYWN4UfigVfDZq9ih9DSexah6d0ZEkQgj9vKUTe4rLxDsyReFxt64tQNhkJm7uLn9qXE6FuiwHnqwuoldGWtsxOqDzGIm7ttBwXBPyWKWK8NzTuSSs5WTLZEejPydlh%2FzzEZBrakjSUnIdP2sH8sWgFZIIfzSp%2BXBsVea19BdjCIgJw3%2FR7ZZh2WrFuG5e%2BfK8TXP10BeISsml3n6YD6gABR3VX%2F7KCrjxVQYU4v05f5cZyywgnEPZ9gClMsF3mREHGs%2BTfR019AQJwLq%2BCYGo3lyqEHJ7ENpqkrQE2clGykIe5KYD%2FGbgekvXzEbTf%2FOzXNXyvtfnGzdQ9TbdFsYYjJtv6fMQEMiccTEmK6kq55se9VCoHu8Ct86tY5CCI8L9TCZmrA0lU6g%3D&meta=tmJZkG%2Fd0eysMRQhYCgDhKJsEt0bbIcOUKEkXIdkIaDvZHq3E1259VyEHXqOVNs8clHqqcL%2F2WFxlFJj%2BYyPNCTIaQsF%2FUz1IiWmiUcyt8jKqKCPc9w2XywwycW3OEw4%2BjwykB5ZLBn9fhVJCf%2BVtnVi%2FVHy7D%2FXHq7zCJSvRPr1Bvxq%2BfoCC9FpeC%2FNBrIFrmjgPL8MMIdreFLuHtxFJQ%3D%3D&iv=1kwUiq2fDCIpn7DxiEMusg%3D%3D>
.

Shipping

 
 
Address

 

Gene labas

viso gero 154

New Iberia, LA 445846
 
Delivery date

 

Thu, Sep 15

Order total

 
*Includes all fees, taxes and discounts* *$12.36*

Payment method

 
GIFTCARD ending in 2617
 

Explore more savings
 
[image: Finish Liquid Rinse Agent, Unscented Scent, 16 Fluid Ounce] 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=y8V2s9zrz5rnNscar5oGQBTyR%2B9R0r5yml5SM511yuDS8vojV1Liu0CAUnXHauxpJ9EsYq9qVW7mOuiSOlYKYiKJBLHxLJ41xwhZvbPal9g%2BtP87NaPxHaY8hYS8AhdwGDwemLfmbqAzpcOo%2BGxpNoC3yam1aC4WV%2FDed5CDwNS5p2spAj8RbCqVe84krBzz3Cf4V4X1BrJ5RVNWKRameN%2BQlr6Tt2oTomjGdddEoJOoPu1Q1ecmn8xRvwJGcCOoNkfZ9eldpKwcLY2zyLZMK2RN%2BGwmf9T9jpJ22ZI%2B1U5p2lD9QrQ8x2GTj8tBSljbJ%2FxE4S8qtQkbLxLzvmiZNDUSf9WuRq28w8DxI3eYoC9t7PkPOTVNTjF%2Fg3i%2FZqrkzGyFeEt2T%2FQ5kwVrqD6o7qFdr2DzCdlSQBT6ZjGmd4AzNwfbNhSIEdbFo1M3HWzzTfid7HRYZCyxOY84iTu2zHRIf0aEI1jdAAxhCeKzEaxCXlOM1QvHGjxoMhPIR2BGjlEbAMsXOY2gsU2N%2BBqstY3Kq8IiqyP4dydHrVcZ0i7M%2FtQ7Xraa%2FxaGuatPMOLf40lSGivc8QLy2y2lXR8QF%2BFVHHOhUxJpSE1deCGXxmWh%2FESiH16zmdE%2FJot4amGIzffUyn%2BANaz3x9knjpLIwx8Ji2ukIX2c0uotJCUDZHf4d1tQJgMWVjriGSANN%2Bg7D7SZbDoX8uOs3Yq7R0voci4znwTGbTG8nN9FTPeJUr1u6HRNfPQBB%2BVpLO0EsyxmkMI%2FxIm0Q0ruZq42Si0Nr%2Fba2jYj8FHNebCMHMPTprstSxlEl5w7SaVDQAj35aofG2ErbwicVdPOh5mGifo8DG8HWkifQAKHmGDO%2FX%2BwP4qdEYCVUCY72a3SN%2FAiziFPWRTKa0puphf1NWRfijZSvvOj607JpcA6%2FB5G6C4FdnB%2FrroCbWrlT3BAnGUunueUHTZPZfPb9HYYAmOgikgN1sIN8o492e03ovl9bRcVCcscHR4QKQoMJ0C6bhj5eBniBad%2Fpgd5oYj0N%2F6zbdHCpDN9GfeUpR63KqYkg7CtguyVT4ZHXbf0FpvZ9l4tiidxkY3sG071U7HcAlo7leph8A%3D%3D&meta=8ooyG9K9uXPj0jDRvBSJVnip9yrKt3Vs7Pkuo6thQ0GQ6rC51ATLfALwKyiSnxx04tFFHFuKD%2Bq%2B9UNQ8KEh2EZ%2B6dxhoMIdx%2BkT9tIYISRQg28oNnCtwKdTxE2Vb09EixWRe6Bmh8nQTeKU7jY8%2FSWXiy9foNR5tBOHBGBl4kfQUhp2tFCcUOXxJM4F3qXjybqNrj9p722KBXbJCQ6Ogg%3D%3D&iv=Qo2A7sxNnd%2FvCHSeQX66mA%3D%3D>

 
 
Finish Liquid Rinse Agent, Unscented Scent, 16 Fluid Ounce 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=%2Bjs%2FWQaYIs9JfGDtwiSWXgIpCkS8PXonC7hRrp%2BmD65rHrwIxScmtO8p9qCk2y9sqhvlCs%2Fxlx3E08D4TrDKfBsPfMvUnBARNb48bEY5Gl9DCalVGEf5xYkdt2mf9nSPLhxX3mNxtbzJulSvMg9ldNPjDr8tg4Cjku04ACaHlXjGXSl80ncclDkcgIrPdvr0zRxUWIQW9fqa18UBOOkq9%2BZpsq7H15nIozxM0zRpNDQUZhvupIM2SWF6GuDRH7lZBvE4qpAE%2BaV6163W9X3cdFhUhRA0OMIuW3QtJu0gZfjts15u%2FS9xkIAmv7F%2B0UzNQ0xbDrblGVB%2FNi7H2jgtUvWDOob1Mt7jzVp05PJsH2i4NGOSvW1PjTGfJEhrrhFyh%2FLaczKOZJ%2F4Uimc3n7hmNt2L8vlIILrYB7trjGigb9KpCJMFjDzYtW7%2FtQpCWtfEr9u7fEJqYdFl%2Byr9cJhqSnkYSU%2BRDqUt24ByJvQi%2Bqcs6FJWffrBy7FNDy%2F%2Fh8LP8EjFFwLkJcwUCEGvgjIgc4juUsGdCjOxQw3iHRokv3PeM%2FvzAszTr0LmwWkrDSI5zc9y10JUqHXM%2BFldqvGCZ70zR04nWK7vjL8Gfk%2BMW4bNqg4%2FbdY%2ByCTUdcYuouQtZ%2FcCmXGFY%2B5B9%2BblRjKbTEZ3ZbB%2BHCztMCPJ2WWtiVB96OOKlmdtm0r6U%2FElm1%2FbL0Uyz3PzPb25nTq10ZDH8QUFf7pDFFguecvrk5mz5SSQH%2FDBQrV8mwj92sy7HJDqBoEr3oCHN1cUrf8L9MGv%2BWybCAUehkrDLS60xaw5aFXVrW4c1NOlwEgpeehceCa%2F5zmacKtYjOcW9JApY%2BG497qfaRLo0Nh9qpiDMX402iGn9eOrNTOKgUGwH%2FiPy%2BPgnMztUnGpfE1k6JO9Alye1yDXJHxydXgCq9xGhAJrYF06riaLzAWIxpjSgQP82GqQalcmThC%2BXiwkiUyzB1vK62Tx5KgzXo3eLGq%2BTApoBgTOw4kTMlFnhdbAuQBGuJ4EsVByjJVRQkMgIkFmdh%2Fcl6AKAnT%2F%2BnsDh9CPu5z0%2BpuaSKsAZQgjpm6D8RTWvM7fLP9r0c4PzSdPxZYqLs5qQ%3D%3D&meta=QLOMvhfMRM5U1Y71b6qw29ZzFK3%2FUzkIi4l5%2FMFiOzw16rK%2FDfYMrsc8DyHkutv3BJniTsLfcoNzMQu%2BGD7MtRiRcj373YfTBjyv93oPb1i%2FMI6yPO9loAdDWCcZKX4QCJlW638LprhVdUyrLlNFfDKmCZrl5Iudri3V1R6%2BTuY1u6PSa0DcI2kf9T68sTBI%2FltydKG1yusgLHilua1uwQ%3D%3D&iv=Bm0b2FQGYldZJPKHS6ARGg%3D%3D>
[image: Dixie Disposable Paper Plates, 8.5 in, 200 count] 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=zxiOyXtwAbICKzZ8%2Bjay6Xksa9FVYeUKieN44L9Q71EAAQQ8HlG8lH34s4vFEXvdF7yS%2F6CKj3E2q2hwer7rHg%2FTNj4ui72CbkOwDspBzXoVTpue6%2FViHF21rGpO1BED5mCNwRexkijJCAlW7S4Fjg1EFK0RXcQ%2B%2BGJFcisU3yuyX0WwFxNo7HlFW670QvBWpnZqt3UTx1LdV2ZE%2FhEEcBdSBECpxc%2B3jPyxm4VLiKzqHj8dDhV4tEqQ%2BVJomr5C3tGU9Kqv6i9b2kW30W0TJcSm12enAjEvklrqt2Jk4ghKHZU5hyaPhjNWPf5lMvlKZub4uZU867MOCKL1N%2B1p63QTLUFewuKs9SBBn%2FrL1WHSfrLE1eRiotfrtitQovHJufPx9SEQNSM7axhOm6qJrvVzArTqnsYwxXC8ep1x1L3Gn1waoGVnJvll33gZSgYxct95F12EPyJJGGR0pzFwx93dwQMeBOUJylcM3Kc7je8lLFN1dz9GExPWq3UjXK7Ws%2F%2F%2FI0AyrcayORPEDWqOL1y6NOqAkkwLydcyFnVhEd8f4v0eTJ95tBorrZiWoZX8mxaDgWJQOe3uNa%2Fb2KyHtzHcz02ARWJsLRqazPzYSSWzIjCu71TQ0GCy6gB2YM5baFoAQR4veyhxw2OzmfNeOgk6gJEXYg%2F1bLj70mkhUQDZtBJ6kfvrZagtCL7YZ9X3e45R6PYtabcijjK42FyEa3fMSF50tU7KSnIEoL13%2B7wAdHm0c3bkptVdXq4X9o3ksrihQFQTKSQCSOTRbi9soAiEZ09tIgvMNyF4NZfTXsmbxyDJ7jONhxtgW%2F1O3SEHDy7JBOyBTkGBNYH4Fq1XxohrFr3gE1%2B4x1X3mf2%2BlyG2zFB8%2BIQkSJPFYeeh7XpCrCg3Ec0Iyjz5zNsx0qBeW3jxZuK9hvNyg6ETcI6gvUdjcrbcy1AgB0XRmhMjFt2t4bsC4avOepgYJ3x%2B71f0kpiIH8xG%2Fg3LdIho2Q6a9d7eiiixIS7xUN3sE0E5B%2FwzLOPONfgcyYrsgfHz2PpZ4%2FgkXeAh6F2A0%2BwpOb3vBR6XQVPfSyIjepWRG%2FotfTh3&meta=T2cgswkTfVeSdDNqp9uLfQYZDeUobftsQ7LabhItQpfnnbU6gl6mHPvBAdseR%2F5Vp2HG1StKcotoOL%2Be4wXB%2BVWr66BmwV%2BcKddqhg701mMyBbURqXu%2FgxHiWOvVh6Ld%2FQZgiOqgrXVM1P6ZqX12axn1UcLuts0hX%2F3wxSTMh5e0EgbgWWANFdrtxSpaL6uWt3UCdIDV1Hi69bxCoOyK9A%3D%3D&iv=3uwipZRRmAva1mDpVJ2VkA%3D%3D>

 
 
Dixie Disposable Paper Plates, 8.5 in, 200 count 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=UtxNvDCuBIiN4Nvk9HGBNnyF0XxipSK17wqR0LFME4n%2BWt5TBOXCktl3HaFvcKAXqmRir9pkF2c2owLm4b7WgIHxj%2F5T8R%2FwysOUY9RMTtpD3JXl%2F94CQxwXOSNR0YqPP84MynZ8jJ%2FY1VedL9AJHP%2FNVxK4GPpEzOGXyoRbHenO%2FfFm0PO8ekSQKJ%2BDw2fIAn889QnuuH0amuQH1N4hVf4NgBY0oQI6zRrHADVtNMraW70eYrYmdIoP6vTtXdBG51%2FmXocuQu8rXc%2BOo7bdFTDo8hV0QDaaDBpamGV9E9AjxC3NGx9PF3SX9yoo6qk0pn8B6%2BZwHRjCFu99eqNBf7MhrY9Y3R8PgLmmI3SQEQS5CsU5L%2BGzAEUx%2BaO8LtHf2XxWbRKZDZGMXtgdNG6L9Ks7eKn8tvJfYreeCDNlDqf%2BiMEqYCl1sNTLwj2QM%2FCCOnR4chnLu8V3e9Q5Y%2Fng8zCoCVf2q2u69FihmLdKSttvD%2BXJQ0l2pF0e8KZR1C846dHgdJ4WPBgY2iZwevygbJjrzKnRvvlT8PwUEb44%2Bk0TJns4OvyZJlhNPX4BoEgQ%2BCS8UbstP6s3TXjlxsjwHUuif%2FrWfHHjahiOky6m3imcTFMurMCep6kosz3qeMkXFSUwCmDocHiighg3IwzGIC08PAWN0eHFKshRTswv6cy%2BBvUdbP5qnCrAahvvRnlBii27YIgOF7C%2BrP7IOf4RY75Zb4IVR25jeA50gVlPgD9RCE6JUmBW5mhT%2F7zoOerwh4mFIfFWrUAq02C373X3Dl6Tx7nqkFzRDAXaVJR89d31ecSMOi5EHKbuNJPN9dGqyNiCzkGatl%2FvNtNvKrxmFv0KLbU%2F2ilZ2iKmsbGqahDU5RAuP3jNCNBqsZwd51DwywgIgVzsJzT5b3apMpNg6RbtIzOnzjSpFGHtQS0EjMJk5hv37hL8q6ExrqdchBdV3DoIeLnfXOOv0%2BWoB3YaaD2h4i%2Frur8tmyXWXMYwLXjPthTysHhmqDYbzIbo0NqYtoTmZx%2FekD4G5cewLgEnUNqJKOJsB9XX%2FPK49rrdh3qrQ%2BnntZpzkgcBAY7CMJbt&meta=AC9jZqrPHAciDhxSEEMuZhuiUoRUK8QR4s90o%2FxV9OXGXp1N6IG1g%2BLhR2Iv7i4sKifO8bT7KkyWaqDB4p%2FTSOccxPVlS%2BOxkjAmSTAEwRGF54okOfv%2FYCVJ54EFxdP8uJISLko3aPj8T62UYPL1B8RgBLigRKL6zwsaI1V9nmLgvKsi50xJUadRfMfqpikEzzgYGEQLsmMmE7KFKMTOWg%3D%3D&iv=nDLKApaH43O%2Fr9BjZY5LGA%3D%3D>
[image: Gain Liquid Laundry Detergent, Original Scent, 64 Loads, 92 fl oz] 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=0YHv3IrUtf6nwlcdQkzYcswhNgXCwvzH1MyDljCflbDgA9vFvJOeADmQvTr5cGtCwGhEMtxhzSj%2FODX4LVfVsl3kgxJBh5Aqgli%2FwNfje42umuqH2LlN45KgFSQMjEWMTFSOuzYwb1PvBJL6kfPw5fZxKlcWD32t4W2%2BtV3NHgMc6TnGlW%2F%2F2yEJpt8oDTYra0qcyrPYevtwAb0iT2DtCYsDvDgkRoQojD%2B7AlAQyc6pc6Knttspi%2BBi4U4kThRmGbYffIfBEj5xqPleTQmuixC70dv%2Fy7rGqSwEB7D4t81x8DcWCPnvyBzcTTDhIjeS64MsmYqqoZwoW4c6Vx5HDZXauaXZjLJ6%2FCTLbR9rqi%2Fb%2BP48WizbXRpIDb3lM5am%2Ba5Urttzu2sX4cu8%2Boxvv6kTHtHKAIQDU5TKN3NUPenF%2B2NreeUG6imtGySOSI%2BrKZRrlicnDJW4xh8uF3iHDnEIjA3oy34AFVmo%2BSWyF5XbItfIsH%2BaVvlDdLi30XS0M7HI7k6rTfvLPxJFWzIu8pWWK8bAYQHbAs0%2FLPxnDNRYrohwz5t1jnDRe%2FuDakuwt2K9jz%2B%2Bl3uLvOQXoO%2BwpMNd4MP25sMQJlk%2FGzuUwtatAb605Fwg8RcNFqrtN%2BSBP5K3ARDcSSPTNd4waJTJumrQR%2F2hGvAtL5IvdpusxMaE4Lq9JEWy37CWEGXI8jvI98sbe%2FS6uu%2BVfAilDHnCFdy%2FnwS6PUWFjhR%2FcI7oQfJrFIL76Zv%2FwLuOB%2BaUqYBUp40%2Fe%2FF6v3bXbgSHi6fCe1GCwphMkdCodnXH1AHxc6L2XYkdh5Cf%2FZW5KRMifXvShnLegYezmsSb4zsOUBh0CDPA%2FKxrkoTG9mbY296T4M8NZfORJKyVhDK%2BxCU3N20r4g9qiT7TS3oaA30Y31610DKwWrsthS2KXoNk0qgwCkMG%2F8KrJpx1wTl2ZVI8ugY5rYIiuHj26V8ZYIvNf4kageQDju1QxiiD4VYoRJDtoiKB3S3kfYIRaWgxktIPxgfB9H5sfxGjU0G%2FRnIImeva7LBixkUn2rdULAKI1uNYr5lCm%2Bo0DE4sjrz0jy1PnXmyOup9pInk92MZ84azjR4DDBa%2FLLt98MClX4S2RDjngzE%3D&meta=1%2FlGUWhQsXFqN7rNygoI8SnbVhWcwP2mluz3UUtOu%2Bsbm6OrdeQlkvHGcYj57bQLHVp9wC2J2v%2BXy4jN1TU8efqr7unEDU%2BY%2BMSUOndzcSrsgpYAqk4WukwbcIeehdFqlA7AyK0pQ4pUblppH7tUiC9n9wT2H0S7a2b55tWy67wtyMy6NtyZobFDnI4HgGcLwMF1AuN72f4mH039pRI%2BdA%3D%3D&iv=963UncljexoKFb9kug1jdQ%3D%3D>

 
 
Gain Liquid Laundry Detergent, Original Scent, 64 Loads, 92 fl oz 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=5tTPcOMrbdVxrcAI5JPvWgfKSZPM3e4ifXo0JrHV18xbgXX5ci8UCrVmOHpJHGDF8p1OcT%2F9cykL0A5GUQ2fQAFL57VHqeDCOcD4ycnoqiSx47kYRv6uK8JZ7MkA03RXTUpOEGrkLSGW6vLbvJMyiDwSDFN0n4OBBo7rT1eRsuldPuzxh6zCFW0C4eSy0xfxGP2YzITDJJ4mB1cSPh7j2UN%2BKYAECoYlbm65h4Rkf67W2YTO7b5yIx5mSmGIh4xtJ5Sc3HA86VjduauiOUUEC%2FjxHCog41pQVBVeRy%2Ffn30GwAk5kJ%2BPdvCrYzonYO0b1FqRmsHMrnKmDzEYmYZKK4JhUFKynZLj8M6BkY7Rp2B%2Bu8%2BFeBQ1OCLHHne34oAUSjmuZe5Z5wabrU4SYJzKMqGbO0jExVka2ELywoLz%2F4OrvBi4XisHCWEVqegGMAwKrwEhIyJ8HnedOpZNfvaiq7kRd4b3MqgKVOVupfe2R9fAhbFDFRoSCpqsUhbUPEWDPJXezeIH3vs9cf7gt7JksZHdfl0U8Vkgj9IOZfz5baq6l9rAF53JRewi%2BKp8VefolPv6Rfthv%2FzjBr8QbYAp5ij%2BXIlHOKj2m87DoGE0YfxjQCtqIRAlohWFY53J4GMYaBGJxzKSsOF34M4zdqb23WJRcKhlu%2BectiL0RxCHssHDlaT01PXs0qX2pwnIV7pLDTe4iBImGizr9dp8VtRDzBdufXlN4ecukW6IVV07bm8pH4bURv3g7ixZTXsdafU25YNc%2BFxjQrgiZ079m9qotUwyBNO%2FfZSW3PGPk43cFbdryMiLfcoVtvFaLncAwSomln4C4I%2B9KKNFIfYfa51nmJsrHi8SHi8cM%2FpClkS%2BpMPHFC2J929Yvee%2BZD2MvNUQLe9ReauTD7fhrw93RrOsCHJKX9k63iN2FV8AXYSilIDhSaIqxasMXjxEAH51cZyJn3XxAZGuymF85913ihp2omUgR%2FG%2BwMjC%2FkjH389FOIGzFFijHGnpsUkCmFUA%2F3arcfwg%2BAgxRz7rhJBLkmRGFok%2FFx8Z0h5QA09K158r6GpIzfve0zwLrgDxrUfgI4ZTVwoPg6BauemFI1TwIr85KAjxw53gebGusPuzCSkvbb8%3D&meta=WAmdMkKS6xEV7jOpp%2FKcvWSrzGHWOWAg7ijAb9MbOTHv5VU8ivlLg9LPVphg5czXrxmAIDGmwfKGnyIENWBuioO5f1uLpKpIQd4gwIJgO7PkThW9G%2FNg6ZdQBhIj0rfV9v%2Fj8ibqGhV4dB9Xe2aEx25buX9n%2F06Lb0qRC0eMFEp3dqLjn0nkGzRl%2FnGZyVqDMrmt4MWAXA%2B1jmKTFVgWKA%3D%3D&iv=qZBTIankCe8ck0fuw8yowA%3D%3D>
[image: Ziploc® Brand Storage Bags with Grip 'n Seal Technology, Gallon, 80 
Count] 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=ULZu%2B%2BPgz8SIcRQpj7LUqAN0Zt7vbq0F%2BcuMj3xsWNtLZFVSJrEevoczct3k0TMZA9Km%2F33dm98XfNiaZRWidLmjcpz6QilgI5MyJEyBiMYjMr0x1rbaYK%2BdzCCd%2BOWiIJNIdoqWTMcb7qY2Bvn0upVSMA%2FkE%2BXlJTAYGpO9CWShTo%2BR6si7YsDYHL7xfucra8QwHGxhxZCjwaz0Bc5gwme2cxp5b0VXJ6Xcu0dZBNNXg%2FehiciKCNomNKu%2F6ObJFWyBgTH7dBLePQ4GSI2MSLjo11CswzYJ0UuFG0OB9XQgAPAvP1BcRoVxMCmxCEH468%2B9GqfyDZuw7retKha1apcJfo2RPWugg%2Bzdwx6S1vG0xry3uVAnO5nO4Ud%2FN9mgPIw2w12h8jza94pXms7IXluRyXoidRzAphvyFowMDYDRXkcwbzu7z6xVcjYTv8RMNw43BApP6V07K0Jf5P5Gu0XhYWXDhkZwZXc%2FIBh81hGaYpQs9U8NG0NxV0cn1tZ3vzZ2BfdSql0%2Bds4QJCaLG6ILiK%2B2lFRW9NtomifveDoI3Xq6IwvI102CGfXNf2%2FoG4MpgF0SQdeaGACYh%2BJjq8Yc4Xr%2BzgWCF3OXa9%2BMufWmr%2FkUOq1JIKgnn3FyrODiMlJIdT1SbCZPNrA%2FWZk3m4UpkeNEFh%2BlfwQeOHIetn0hCJ29AS9egqS3Ic8kdjuqwyi68aPk1Ukme2T59utLpWkNi8usbGILae%2BjYB830EUn3Syok7Qzrao5JdR3j8AKOaHg9XXgcg6XwSvqFvfh7%2Fc5b3A04A8LBPe54gc7HfCPOt86FQhoxpz2JrgKLlRu6gyITmzGvYJ0u1A0F5ZFWTSdZwRuXGjLHOkHGrJv5%2BiuITYQvdX784EtwsgigcUqi43veksr8FLdHN0ek71bsIiTWo%2FaUB6NaqIPrer56bpr5VkeXyqEUSLGy4t%2BhtlY1HiQDpiUDNxxDnvnp3QJpD9yEHI74YX6hubrcq8my0rHYSKzJzM5DRA8pk4nMJNyJ6vUH1tR%2Bi5ijkTfWvqiDLZB7il3b3ODOMUxZtCfLy61uUzMgEP8BWBwkJP%2FEr1BD%2B23SCVVpUkzHJj%2F%2BuKz6s1ryjPv2F7K2Q0azkYvbMA%3D&meta=4stpEx%2BMgp9tgGH2lbgFl08A6J8ZfIzczw3MOetPBvCFkpIWkyhN1tWH2pP%2F7nRTQGieLSlQWLW8wOqY6TnAtmX0Z%2FsDyPgPKydhGUiJvPKeB%2FqDoRBmnLauptKgIvnJNUoN1c1EX3Rygh7VZ7GKd8H%2FLAEjQPcX1nINh9ERksLCtAVc%2BKdR6y59U62%2Bc2gm3J3EFzmbFhgb%2BwELfXxQEw%3D%3D&iv=7mk1mvLlW%2BTns9RgO3cS5g%3D%3D>

 
 
Ziploc® Brand Storage Bags with Grip 'n Seal Technology, Gallon, 80 Count 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=z7c1hyiTykoWoEdCdppd8qb9THM8u0ura9M0SPjw83jeN2ERQ3SVMZts5Huk3kiSOG1cqBnX8UL2%2BZqOMcK%2FO9LQne5KX%2FFcy0RY5Voj0AdVtam0gDRjp1Fof2dfL%2BBfnGTZ%2BLjKtqvHKaKKrRZBMVmzv%2BhXNYvGvSIcrDn9WEkVRHb474YB8O7qvM3mwRCt8o3Yp9Z7P%2FuEXmSUuKB%2B2YN7GK5k%2F8QSCHZVHIgMUPhdJtdmkolMq%2FxXnXaXgH%2Fah0STwu6tRWX5lE4UAN4QF9ljc5DBhbJR2FJwQH8erA%2FfJbx%2FlWyh83mLqOkkrLtvKEDbsfsXJVtLKXk3YrNuMPhWlMCncJk%2BmcEQRJ6sc3KwQTpFwXz3qoc3206R29GVjnToffwsk4Ax9VJBNeQWwenBCpewz1kONSRYXk8u27kyYio5Vk1YUcBkvfMpMD6I0rYPnUHbd3IhBaNh5mkQ0KE4j3uhAH%2FXnyK0RRoOenx0XnV2CeHZ2asC7eVXqSyC%2FitAtZYmP4cJP2bk6g3fP59p3zeo5hvBLhcUIRyIEPdgEHbEEzykIPxMC88ydcGRSUpjVfG5j1XaTtPP53jncn%2FrUvG37t5fUIYtp7q4FyVJgHxZHReEzVLOprOAnfyBU5ynL%2BnDSjSA9QqquwiJsT0tERzO%2FU2XR0FID8NUOuj3RtgaMiSywkh1hOMMjPElcwm%2B3dYWcAbGt8BgH4SDBPIMqcZjHZvoHAd4L4nEjq89S5oB0lD6gLdxDaGPynHV9QFvH77iTtoMzL105oNPCoFOUQQOo7YXmauRb1UHECvd3U0xecVfcfo2Cr6A8DbVAZT5M73G1bhskZRFYE9U9nT96YlwbR%2FRZ7UonvbTMnv7ZNf727eFmWEoq64jStnibg45VKXG7%2FTzMB7OJ%2BdXowrzqw3eWS2CDGze8Qdec2bcD07%2FZ5kLwfrPqJ2KwnY4rv4Efu254cKibGaaF5lcUURbxNzLmMuZBx9O%2BfKwMj8Hj%2FvdklItLJymEnCJoQv69uzAV23ieyDYclKF7Y8LFOFcSILajhCsmSU5E1%2F%2F%2Fyww0WgWanyo1odEZscgfngNkIQniJh9lDzVNSP7%2F6gwBh5T9UsfGOmhMJU%2B1PQ%2BR%2FA%3D&meta=O3JlXUCDyBkOtDp5ZnOGxVVuokNRaxiwO8SQbG3%2FEuUbT4ZkMWbAiKMoV7HbuAOcO6jkR8ShnSVQz0KxvHWJ%2Brinv%2BZ0Hb20R%2BVzKuaDqzxvL1Rp7atyvBRQ2BiP9o%2BbwdzcV8l6hRa0ZHA%2FquKFL0SyD5UJyWrkrdsK2aWIwHSNyxpHWHDKdJiDBeAITS%2FUAKLWxvLvl1GRW0QEDgLdNg%3D%3D&iv=oGNaxcsBDmHfwjoQwvfRDQ%3D%3D>
 

 
Shop anywhere with the Walmart app
 
[image: Get it on Google Play] 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=UQnkLgRuecgzqY2%2Fz%2FlpexoGp2KQgHwC0BsPrGnspS%2BQ%2BUPMPV9dx0VMJgoJBPwO8vvTOZOJ7ELf3QkUkGYz4dC1DkUghIA1Rw67OWbO3B99ITSUmsFDhOGqI16zoVj2Mtlm1jo1Z9eQ6RbiefkPcJM2LPZGmaKLt%2FX%2FqtllqHwQkmS1kFXDqafZg5W8W%2B2lT0A0a3Rvqwhwyz67h%2FAuYGeEZUxZ3TRirbO691BY%2F6ElRUL7JpxJ83fQWsQpZCbPJYGds4Nexi3wUAqhaHirEQ4S%2BYTqhGQW2y9%2Buwn%2FyB8JEDTEE3b9oS4ptq%2FpmolvNBM3J31ie%2B0OoQPkIPG99o493I6CcFe%2B6gIzH8VtxYRyv1rGqWP9VE%2B1M2audU19bsejOOtwnMwPY1BqriyKlcewQ%2BZkKfJbbc1SICZrf4t4hh0PJa8YHvywDEAm%2BiKl&meta=ofddsNBInzwVKuh8zsKA9De%2B%2BxIuv2MjcYoJqzmPCuCnCS1ZRrhSE2rv9ImeH2dRc6mONVTiS%2BfZpvy%2BpCx0UDahFLMK3U%2FCXDZbSwYQ3%2B0vNNnobCLxQDqnAdYnKI2ujDxUQs9ZWs3CzC0ZT20MWpr5QSsWxWi5ZuqR0MnhCUUr5r2Ahz62i%2FibRjwzk8KT5nZwxYw5y%2BMhGTILEkiSNQ%3D%3D&iv=uWvzRupoF5AYtSGRye1%2B0w%3D%3D> [image: 
Download on the App Store] 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=gh8vBHNBeTZHeMdQ7XQSA8warerrHUC9KGVGm8nXmnRudDJddm84zUxaOCzfZ2MF8jiTwFg%2FrFiFYh9M5BsdSlPWU774kEBzbkxBOjCe9wLrXl6NuNmQA35IZ1BhxSi3L97SQejqrBJGGMfmtLt%2F1wzwXRZE%2FemvD5afvJgbgWxmDLgLWn0DqmNWvmPzTJP8OVonJ1h%2B%2FOosfsqeG0dFchT1cm8iHRMKA3LxSAR5NTEFA7UZdPdTiQM4QZ8g5WH46SKamL0saCvHbBtbPDWHFOhutFEOBK3LCrX5iAjYD3xk%2ByjCeZLzirafKjOcSW6BdBXTSXToZxCObRV%2BZXIo3SkKekE6PwaCStM0FPrUmmjf82W5XzVHe7drZN44pSthsr7baCeTAT%2BDSD0WNa6tt7K9tofsHHAtVLy62dcREWPiUq7oInSczNoYNktXbTlvuMIQjicCALFaIbNXRo1lbQ%3D%3D&meta=Eqmdzb5cVtyZQ5AgEmI%2BpSBFicD9x58bL2lh56csWZWUJFnelShcOzSmInIBt%2FSbq9cM4feaInRgh4%2BCdQMi9u%2BaMwNRhwi5s9fcQgEFLn89UEugjEol5xdqMMc3N4IW0ex8H%2FGG7AmM58%2Bi6%2FKJMbHpX7IqgitfG2FnaVOCxf4SWYn56azKRMZ6qYnfvlLhf5ZdOyg2OXLjo8wDpdK2CQ%3D%3D&iv=STIsGsTrQW9m0iwnS1kKbw%3D%3D>
 

*Questions? *Visit our Help Center 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=nVaRbhVcu%2BvAKOdfqwMyxJgiiMeNCV%2FCea6rm53nOw%2F2ZG5K%2FgAgev2AbJfO3AzTQPj7179v292KKhRUrydgRLZ0Qh6aGSmYxsAVnZYIUuwgaxbIfxc0lTO5Y7S%2Fe6d69ZhNjJCpwwMliLAp%2F6hx7uFwAhHGKIQt4eDVZITfdHllmburmTfQJK0VWb7Hku1TEX0JxoKvqsR9YPo2EzKzlG2jiJGMO2mIS%2BV5pw4NvqtrgLuKLOh59f6%2BR%2B5DpL8EuYDgFaK%2Fk%2FsKzjV6ERa53bFfTYstf2uEFU1%2BEHisBGwoxGAnSyI0fBdZ2JrvMYuku%2F3Oqaj1ZvDcuEbnP1s03ABiapTs8AQVOqAbc0vaPgkuVqbz2YVdWY90w2YRaF5opWpZq2ZCLxKA%2BeWGPAcrIksIaxaV7bYZoQ1OwlOh%2F58%3D&meta=fiELIiTEF2SSRh%2F%2BElqDNqQFIkgHfi9HbjPbkaDSnMAPLQYvxE7X96I454sKuw3%2FegTuu3wYHZhP9ivfjTBzo9o3teRPoUUFOuc5rfg%2B%2ByC4Rxg6%2FYCq8mL%2Bk%2BjQbQEU7V3hUobHSmVUNXcoGKW%2BVc7LTq%2FAJJquLgdf6v4y0gkFRaGbAy43yW%2Fo%2F5qtwkT83bBWkAOktso30epG2m6H7A%3D%3D&iv=NombUkUI5HkWLMvow9Vq2g%3D%3D>
 
[image: Twitter] 
<https://w-mt.co/glass-web/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=y6c%2BsYW%2Bcz9DjDDzts2codkFRZB68iM13t%2F3R9Hn%2BD2%2FChrQpSTdSGXMkmPzfq3rI6Dg2%2B%2FekCpX27h4aU%2Fodq%2B47sWWUED9VP2sYxCcF80BT2QpE6nZsuA0IseSuuk4m2hC0k2LRwleRxh9cE%2FfqGpgxQ9J3SmylEvkyEYbdosMj0jAY9ATE386DkWSZknrtj1%2BAfWNyQEiqgiDF3Abhggx%2BqcAgtfifwfLsen1CX2bUD7c6oG2p9WZzVrLPYz%2B7SPOE6uMpbDehQixxN84rQhF2IWBDhOZewN6rjwNBSLGcm5yNixeq7CiXByvgfTP92W%2FTPmRjIbh%2FTrrEk%2Ba4HxilJpKLT8mehJILKQDSt1z9a9iCysfFf0p9tjlAULw%2FYDGTzTTWwUP914JYUl%2BFoqP8QkxJ9mc4INzuABZ%2FSKA9xQE8k5kO%2ByHRwY0bqav&meta=8tcfhT5ub4MQSGPD1n2NYK6a3oLWDritCHGZ59LxP0B5AvWBnYuRYJVQJzv%2B3CeRGM9AtsXmD%2FANTzEiSoXH%2BmdLtAXTFtSXvrYtgOemhqWhxIWpNlj7zVwVcm2ADr667DqnLgQckbN9gEt%2FVUrVO7sluuiZPcxz3ImObmrv2eEGLVHB7fFIbICmraU2DBznKPesNHW9Tx7FLIrLEIJVUw%3D%3D&iv=GGWgDKVvTRTx%2B%2BXMBJ0qig%3D%3D> [image: 
Pinterest] 
<https://w-mt.co/glass-web/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=YQBBHus2ysAmtWVefIQVVCrrUVKHUrzUveRTZ%2FfWJS66qvfD5d4lmyyvPDRNb5jkRuZ31eKK0bsmaPrIbQ9S0G0%2FJf6gyClG0MhLQRzIPdJ%2FsCtDB97uX1ni4vYMRg0isSTrHFs99zve3r39C9149Gbeo39Sl0rPzMlRiZ0Y36ZWRznr7%2BdtH4w%2BazjO5czZKC%2Fnn7kZRxgSUcYbEAiZGSPWAVOnc5UokNwwyRtPZ0c8fUCHY6F3zub3iXG2%2F8SVoPiYHxtlh1ZCWp1j%2B3i4nYSH49R96RbCyT2a8ykqigRiHvOoioGfF9fYA%2Fq%2FeRJbOP74F5s%2FfYtcduaL%2BHszPS5G%2BJBrUVlL6RLDGwy8zUZfSxsu2pgFKwIkr0wyTSOU%2BdUEcYBW5B8PsNC44WMOdmj87cudYnE%2BA4aF8Nv43IYYacNKm6av5qwp3uGkAUWt&meta=ItQmpXq9f%2BmCT8%2Fl%2FXYiZ6RQ%2BNOhuL2Vl3%2Br67rr1jVg9WsSQeTlJVW94yEbGkkNxgIy5dlcGJTl8yxSqcADwGr2Jk97eo1YcPaqm0d4OV0QyZKpa18XLw67GdOKKAipt5FCCQEPAwIPSzyBV3H3Q2O%2FKtlKyy3xA%2BYyrDfizBV3RGywgPm5MJHy%2FS7eULMc2Yqd5SYtFZC%2FeddRq%2FE3EA%3D%3D&iv=fzehrkl6uxbpu2%2Bm%2FIEeiA%3D%3D> [image: 
Facebook] 
<https://w-mt.co/glass-web/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=Xh7ntdxq%2F%2BnqfJ9ugZN6UVvKrpb3siK72PSF2QX9XmQHf8Cn5pN7ReX3kUitcReZlDnBXpIrYv101kW0KF2drrvxCikUGaXm0BZ5q9Vrh6zT5jbiEVOkQNf8OfCWIqaLEYHtBzEpDjfkxLShOrnSqj6hF2QFDyoUN2voxgAnID0KVb4kbwaVpwWuhVSYPf5cSukL004rbQUxQtznx8%2F85m%2BWzk2Rli8l4baEHfQWMKbiyNkdviYxTdVyvi0WgxNL5XUmq68RO9UlQzOojdscqYJFBONp%2FwVaRoIRcaHSNkZoPtfqKK6iwdj3pseR%2FZpYOC9Gc0qwY%2FdplwoPPHubPqJXziJTHfkLQgIrHIuEFtfV4TMtO4WRDmlsSvHbLtVOAhSl3nal0l1dUV7ymNttxrB9ZU%2Fed8wu0br8VJvQnXJ98rBiBgjT1zmi%2BNS97CeO&meta=iEKCYwHqgJAMpchhdsB2VHBnqZbdGPqgMFAkqVsKHDQDwdvyA5ysllqGZKRNhoGw2vDVNH9kQmiFwHoppf2ucCdtttKxiq0HCbIUrAqhudVcURz9qCovX4lJTzxHvNChXHRpTXjb28N6OPzLBBv920HhEgfocvLIFkwuwgwEHYDMGfqbjKq9ZmHumNamDd%2FHBLeY%2F9BKI3CpFd%2FpuKiB%2Fw%3D%3D&iv=wUV60gBzFwjWqunCJ6fuKw%3D%3D> [image: 
Youtube] 
<https://w-mt.co/glass-web/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=8dvRE3XqtzIfAdo3QkxAOxOn7wfCQfI6tx1QYonK5Vh1jrJx%2FN9095Ye31Uw8x%2F4JpGvUUklj%2FLRcNk1Bfanmi7U%2BKeYHktQWEvu2Chyf8ERcOXIyNt%2BGMqGzQtlwKzMOk%2BHvxWp%2FbRDip3hARR283yRut01hzM3S8e4lzd5JgmXOX60YAOornNQh4Y418CxS0uK9XvJJa62fLEfLWwLZP%2BFwYKM3Fz5mUyKU%2BvEof6jQyzKQ6T8UdTrj6G1v3Wd7ZvWUZB%2FMqgaooMB35of%2BhkO6mUWONJ5SYxINhL7rRkpBUWwfnTTLwBNs2Xy2gBqk0v%2F0qohVfzgdZtiXBQwgT6g5%2Bu%2Foe6zTHEPjtahX25NfRQxoa5eda1MaS5UXRwS%2FoZhZMADIbJt9TQizXeY6yL6TZY80Q9ItFK3MERfqrkEtrR2Y3ZxBoHBAulV%2FRQe&meta=MyWpSZFwQ%2BklP%2BEoQuAjIr8mD3uZcjyLwdeuQD4z56p3H6iQyr25DUuK6aWQzI%2BduVnV%2F7Arx4jx%2BD6gGKNPrFUInqxtDPnYzIAwyeVwOYQ1dDdo2BeI9ngtRujyEK%2BOYvDUrNB6Ma5CbaQMX4pwVD%2FQkkzhno1E938bWK7GsZFxcocniSIWQYYyIl1XSNKOzvhzrmgz5n%2FtrtYU3EAydw%3D%3D&iv=Eg6ZMvjkzf%2FfZMIrciVkYg%3D%3D> [image: 
Instagram] 
<https://w-mt.co/glass-web/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=Enbq7ixRavGmx2naz3XcqknpwgP3yeSsWhUKcEtHKMHEg4nfwp86IKXHAVbgD4TfLaLmUwZnBNblREZHnL0%2FTMBG9sTneQyL0UOnhpCgvMLGZPQGC6CiAwFIqhDvdn0Z%2FCNUhAb2fBlf2yoFxyHXYLV%2BHAg7hwpYHdyixnIOTJQgzaOFiEIowecXEdjsQ4F%2BtjIt04vyr6RUT2Do5UiwbSbWcaaLSVOP7Zmspxg6d05Khe2H1%2FdEKtktFJ%2BYj%2FHXHBh8IoiSi4fyMs7u4H5llPE3wML27MiJDsunihg2RuXbuS%2FVIIIGblfv1FEsVXqPbihGy4ran9TVtnynmamQnwBlNGrz7L6AZjFgg%2FJYV5FLQECQmDdRsgNqYY2vgMLglDmccjkfdAFpNP12R27lw13ML3u5mCXUSYrAyi9EKD3XLpzjANmYjjEYdWE5EJgG&meta=wIO0ePtudoKruXwACPoi6O5Z7dqVeajm%2FCyKa70SlyWCz6NRd0TvtdSiy5Te9LnC87nei7KAso3C0viVuXQ1PTMN2swUzl3t4d6VDkUhIaRKcfgK4J29bxMjxyFI%2FiZydTA1ZaETwOIEe%2FxVU5dL7wjWBtnF4j6i8y2KjC3H2c%2FNrct6ugmp9YvtYylaQIuzui4JgegC0xzzl8G%2FjTM3GQ%3D%3D&iv=kGvZIQcrSQtpo0o0Ed4Ckw%3D%3D>
 

Walmart protects your security and privacy. We will never ask for personal 
information (such as passwords or credit card numbers) in an email. If you 
receive such a request, please do not respond. Learn more 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=bs8%2FgVLav0NPQk29SKD45WJmzV9LJTCLn87XPGg8ya3gl4NDCDVhQ4Za1G8GfMAnR8YWedtlfzBcx8NQBHLGfpPUP5oYhDAaK9E8ouFz7WRhpDl2JHQ3%2FPYFC1uIyIkNfvl%2F%2FWT%2FShqJFyefQ6cBIwr58bZpkJGjLycKPiz3fzKyuro6pu8OuZkrBpdYMmz5EhGp%2FwE1feN1UaBkDaloLhsdMvfAuLH7k4QjMSVpnyPf7BsYsHgvvrxA9Om%2BtzUdPtquQ44eM2DFjpCQlK2kB6s40MypH0rIo4U8955FGCHbXbKDdhh43gPVEsbofghNgTIlppfYQPIYqJO6PTQvDE6lX9mL9baWwwlHL3hhCFW8yEuEDy1tr6p%2BddfB767yI0eqD3FwUP7siTpVdYUBwS6Rjhfby8tr1V0lPoCPmSruAoj5rGfPJ2TaLjQ8XDoAIIUqxzFzlHZQNWW%2BEdZlAw%3D%3D&meta=T8FFSQyk9sRYTwUdZ7oea0UZd5hV4yk05PV74TXb9UgRLXvacalsRY0wDcuGD2tM3M1MoU7FOVoKp0IszMNYY18stc2vtTbUIpmBV26ObKVjXOLZPmsdtkBtrVA%2BSWTjjBxNcmbZlHoIersvgQ%2BfW6qd8kextL8b%2FzcS9lawSpQvOxhIDERFIxNvvarAiRijCWpHmGJ6g%2B8Y5vZU%2F3wBMg%3D%3D&iv=zmHQuNKDjJFVf14CmLpKoQ%3D%3D> 
about online safety and see our Privacy Policy 
<https://w-mt.co/g/rptrcks/comm-smart-app/services/tracking/clickTracker?redirectTo=HuBKUAzmBU4wFlZYzJchpuo1sRkrJePOJZA7gZ2y54fGZtyffT4fQkNpg70rLMX%2FA2PMkLYUHA4UVgh6BJmgmCbp%2BdYSnzvu0EGHABoY56ccpt9Upc3X7BuZcrwzyhg2OjBSF4lhGBfYuiOlzR%2BB9TB37%2FE1qm9tvVMdv6ayIxj%2BQkJdpH1qwzNWu%2FXJCleoDPW3x6MC64L12XcGIgG0FkBpjnbu4DIktvfTPjG9kPogwt0BaOw2rCy9Au6xpp1hgRtAhBvhLTwXASocOMdqAuqoDnJ3hNLXOGgCsjgqf0Uknt94pNpEsfv1IholRt6XAhmlvOvHrNLdkyI0L5nPmZZVjiJ024ISZ3Y0PFwpvkzSVCT6tSZfQo1NbtLnmEf5buhOPtXoqbKGDNuPJwgDJw1Yfb6QaZE4uVZFI7d0twL5umfUWQYMUTKzQO1L9w3XFR4DpHmsJyrZ%2BqdPk63vnMR13UvOmj25hzyAdNll1vY%3D&meta=8Y7aBNcCd3kIU6U3MjBZkN7SiKNqA%2FAzmg82KbwllXNICnhQxL7%2BGO7xDzU5aepBp2syvgtRxz0NzubOXEu01mk6eG3VsOrckGOzeVElOD1A1yc62M7S4yi7rCRqk9WFgMg6owYLj5G54m14O9JW5TnX7QKc9A8HVPW50Rm28gk58vZ%2FQsHuVC5hmSlP%2FhBh03ubMsnOyk3gNnTkziZ4WQ%3D%3D&iv=k65uLhDhbnvqTybMM4cjiA%3D%3D>
.
 

Please do not reply to this email. This mailbox is not monitored.
 

© 2022 Walmart. All rights reserved.

"
```

```css
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Walmart");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      
      var sub = messages[j].getSubject();
      var dat = messages[j].getDate();
      var bodyContents = messages[j].getPlainBody();
 
    
      
      

      ss.appendRow([ sub, dat , bodyContents])
    }
      threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).