# Extract some google email information into google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Hi following the question in this thread [Google Script to pull certain information from email and put in a Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893509/google-script-to-pull-certain-information-from-email-and-put-in-a-sheet)

I am really interested to understand if is it possible to extract multiple parts of the email.

For example, if I have two different blocks inside my email like

Item#: SS10MM
Product Description: 10mm SOCKET
Vendor: Store
Vendor Item Code: 10MSS
Complaint: Lost another one, really wish you could put a GPS chip in these!

may I extract both?

thanks a lot

```
  var LABEL_PENDING = "pending";
  var LABEL_DONE = "done";

  // processPending(sheet)
  // Process any pending emails and then move them to done
  function processPending_(sheet) {

  // Get out labels by name
  var label_pending = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(LABEL_PENDING);
  var label_done = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(LABEL_DONE);

// The threads currently assigned to the 'pending' label
  var threads = label_pending.getThreads();

  // Process each one in turn, assuming there's only a single
  // message in each thread
  for (var t in threads) {
    var thread = threads[t];

    // Gets the message body
    var message = thread.getMessages()[0].getPlainBody();
    Logger.log(message);
    // Process the messages here
    message = message.substr(message.search("Item#:")); //Get the beginning of the important part + cut off the beginning
    Logger.log(message);
    message = message.split("\n");
    Logger.log(message[0].split(": ")[1]);

    var data = [message[0].split(": ")[1], //Item#
                message[1].split(": ")[1], //Prod. Desc.
                message[2].split(": ")[1], //Vendor
                message[3].split(": ")[1], //Ven. Item Code
                message[4].split(": ")[1] //Complaint
               ];
    // Add message to sheet
    sheet.appendRow(data);

    // Set to 'done' by exchanging labels
    thread.removeLabel(label_pending);
    thread.addLabel(label_done);
  }
}
```

Comment: The body of an email is just a string so you can use regex or slice or any string method of your choice.

Comment: Sorry, probably is not well formatted but every part is on a different line.